# Workflow stuck and not cancellable

Tags: github, github-actions

I did a misconfiguration with `concurrency`, initially in the root of my GitHub Actions workflow, and moved to a sub workflow (`workflow_call`).

Since, I have a workflow that is stuck with label:

[image]

I tried to cancel it with `gh` official CLI, response: `gh: Cannot cancel a workflow run that is completed. (HTTP 409)`

[image]

I also found this **other workflow** to be stuck, I also tried to cancel it with github api response : `{}`

[image]

Since all my following workflow are stuck.

According to GitHub, it is possible to [force cancel a workflow](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-21-github-actions-force-cancel-workflows/) using the API, but this doesn't work.

[This](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#force-cancel-a-workflow-run) is the more detailled force cancel workflow documentation.

How can I force stop a GitHub Actions workflow?

Comment: It would be nice to be able to reproduce your issue with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Could you share this `Update Jira Issue` step (with the whole job as well) to see how it was configured? It looks like the workflow is waiting for a manual approval from an environment, is it correct?

Comment: no there is no manual approval, the whole project is available at https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-main/tree/3e2dce65a743cf4a03f64eda035dc91dd89ce0ef/.github/workflows , I give this sha because after we reverted a concurrency commit to restore our CIs, as we were totally blocked. the workflow in question is `dev_on_push_workflow_main.yml`

Comment: For what I understand after looking at your repo, cancelling [this run](https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-main/actions/runs/7476235346) would allow you to cancel [the run you shared in your question](https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-main/actions/runs/7487697891). For some reason GitHub didn't stop the runner 2 days ago (it probably was during [the outage](https://www.githubstatus.com/history?page=1) that occurred on that day).